# How can I edit a root file on a non-jailbroken iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, fuse

I often have to boot into OS X mode and use Xcode and so on for some Phonegap iOS development but it would be much easier to just edit the Javascript files I'm working on in Ubuntu, if that were possible. I know it is at least possible to access the files in read only without jailbreaking, but that was on OS X with third party software.

Experimenting ifuse has so far been a failure - only yielding access to a few things, not the /var/ folder I need, and it looks like it's author stopped working on it 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

That is the whole idea of jail breaking: the ability to edit files on the disc that are owned by `root`. Either you jailbreak the iPad and you can edit the files in /var directly or you can not.
Unless you find out the root password ;)

---

Regarding the link in comment.

There are 3 situations:

1. The software you get when you buy Apple products.
2. 3rd party software that replaces the software Apple put on the device and enhance the current features. These use the permissions and or directories that are already open on the device. This includes (but is not limited to) tethering (browsing over the iPad; basically this is telling the kernel to use a module), adding music or pictures, manage installed applications, synch  addressbook/calendars/notes and bookmarks. These things can be added without having root access. They add files to userspace.
3. Software Apple does not want you to install on the device. These are for instance rootkits, ssh and/or telnet connections. These require you to jailbreak so you can become the root user of the device.

The partition where /var/ is located is most likely mounted as Read Only (heck you can even assume that the whole system is mounted Read Only and only the user partition is Read/Write). To change this you need to jailbreak: then you can umount the partition, remount it as read-write and change content to it. Any Apple product that is capable of writing to /var/ (if they even make this possible) is more than likely going to do something similar: remount the partition to read-write , write the files and remount read-only whilst making sure along the way it is done with untampered software Apple wrote.

Comment: I suspect those are not the only methods because of statements like "This is a Linux Kernel driver that adds support for iPhone tethering through USB cables. Unlike other solutions out there, you don't need to jailbreak your phone or install third-party proxy applications." http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=35356 and http://www.libimobiledevice.org "does not require jailbreaking".

Comment: I still think there are other methods possible because http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/ says it doesn't require jailbreaking and it has read AND write access! I will boot into OS X and confirm.

Comment: I just confirmed I can do it on OS X, and it should work on Windows. I don't know if it's userspace or not. It might be actually. Maybe this screenshot I just took will help: http://i.imgur.com/prSjS.png - iExplorer shows all apps, and they have an .app directory in it, and I can copy, delete, and add files. I just modified a JS file of my app and ran it on the iPad  just fine.

Comment: I can get a similar list of apps with ifuse but when I try opening my app from the list I get 'Unhandled Apple File Control error (7).' so that might be something solvable (I'm investigating more - I did Google it before though).

Comment: regarding the error: http://fuelledbykrawu.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/how-to-fix-unhandled-error-lockdown-in-ubuntu-while-attempting-to-mount-an-ios5-device/

Comment: Hey thanks - I suspect that is a different error but I have done the steps it mentions and the error still exists, but will now reboot and retry again.

Comment: Yep I still get the same error after restarting. I will try mounting it in a terminal.