# Is there an Ubuntu alternative to iExplorer (formerly iPhone Explorer)?

Tags: software-recommendation, filesystem, iphone

I'm trying to view the entire contents of my iPhone in Ubuntu 10.04.

I'm able to mount and view the digital media folders, but I'm looking for behavior more like the Mac/Windows iExplorer app that will list the /var folder as well as Applications, etc rather than just making it look like an external filesystem.

I've found a few options that require jailbreak but I'd rather not go that route if it's at all possible.

Thanks!

Comment: What about running iExplorer thru WINE? OK, maybe not a real solution... but without jailbreak I don't know any other way :/

Comment: (also, jailbreak is the same than running sudo in Ubuntu... :P )

Comment: WINE is worth a try. I'll look into it. Also, I'm kind ofoa n00b at *nix stuff, so... if I just mounted the phone somehow and ran sudos on its' FS would that give the same effect?

Comment: Well... I'm not sure. I have a jailbroken iPad, but even if I use a lot the terminal I can't say you if the iPhone itself would give you access from Ubuntu. iOS comes with so few tools... :/

Comment: The most simmilar feature is OpenSSH + SSHFS, which would allow you to directly mount the SSD from the root folder. Difficult for a common user, not so difficult for a hacker :P (obviously, just if you've done jailbreak before)

Comment: Let me find anything useful without jailbreak... :)

Comment: Somebody asked the same than you in May: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139295/how-can-i-edit-a-root-file-on-a-non-jailbroken-ipad

Comment: (I suppose that you're trying to access to /var/mobile/Applications)

Comment: Also... did you know that the iOS version of Vim allows you to explore the phone's file system without jailbreak? :P

Comment: OK... it seems that nobody did anything like iExplorer in Ubuntu... D:

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to open the root ('/') folder in Ubuntu:

1) Thru WINE: try to load the iPhone in WINE and to run iExplorer.

2) Jailbreak your iPhone, install OpenSSH in your iPhone and run SSHFS in your computer. To do this:

- Connect the iPhone and the PC/Mac to the same Wi-Fi.
- Install OpenSSH from Cydia. Easy, huh?
- Install SSHFS in Ubuntu. Open a terminal window and run `sudo apt-get install fuse-utils sshfs`
- Get the iPhone's IP going to Settings > Wi-Fi > [blue circle with arrow next to your Wi-Fi] > IP Address.
- Create a mountpount with, for example, `sudo mkdir /mnt/iphone`, followed by `sudo chown [myuser] /mnt/iphone` (obviously, replace [myuser] with your username)
- Unlock the iPhone. Don't lock it until you logged in.
- Now mount with `sshfs root@[iPhone's IP]:/ /mnt/iphone` It will ask the root password.

The default root's password in iOS is `alpine`, change it to anything you want opening the iPhone terminal, logging into root and typing `passwd`. This is the only security hole in jailbreak, but it's so easy to fix it that anybody who knows how to jailbreak can do it!

Logging with root in / is not the only way to access the iPhone. For example, you can open the /var/mobile folder using the mobile user with `sshfs mobile@[iPhone's IP]:/var/mobile /mnt/iphone`. Password is (of course) `alpine`

To unmount the iPhone, check that you're not manipulating files and run `fusermount -u /mnt/iphone`. If you have problems unmounting, try first `killall sshfs`

3) Run iExplorer in a virtual Windows using, for example, Virtualbox. Too slow for some computers, very simmilar to running WINE, and you need to have a Windows copy. Anyway, it's the same than running in a Windows PC.